# scale_x_discrete does not label N/A values

Tags: r, histogram, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot a histogram which contains some N/A values. When I label the x axis then my N/A bar will remain unlabelled (1), but when I instead not label my histogram, an automatic label for my N/A values appear (2).

How can I achieve to get my N/A values to be labelled as such?

(1) labelled histogram - **lack of a label for N/A values!**

```
doforaliving <- factor(rawdata$Q009)
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x=doforaliving)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5) + xlab("") + ylab("Number of Participants") + ggtitle("Are you working or studying?") + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "na.value"), labels=c("Working", "Searching for work", "Continuing my studies", "Other", "NA"))
```

[image: labelled histogram]

(2) unlabelled histogram - **N/A values are labelled!**

```
doforaliving <- factor(rawdata$Q009)
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x=doforaliving)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5) + xlab("") + ylab("Number of Participants") + ggtitle("Are you working or studying?")
```

[image: unlabelled histogram]

Comment: 1) provide a sample of your data
2) do what @lukeA suggested, ie, force a label
3) subset the data without NAs and `droplevels`
4) change your `factor(..., levels = c())`
5) provide a sample of your data
6) post the `str()` of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you provided, I'd say: replace `na.value` by `NA`:

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
rawdata <- data.frame(doforaliving=as.factor(c(sample(1:4, 100, replace=T), rep(NA, 10))))
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x=doforaliving)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5) + xlab("") + 
  ylab("Number of Participants") + 
  ggtitle("Are you working or studying?") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4",NA), 
                   labels=c("Working", "Searching for work", "Continuing my studies", "Other", "NA"))
```

[image]

Comment: @TilHund, Because your x-axis is a factor you don't need `breaks` here, it's enough with `labels`. Neither is `binwidth` necessary.

Comment: @ Henrik, thank you. That is even better! I still have to learn a lot about R and ggplot2!

Comment: This solution does not work anymore (`ggplot2` v. 3.4.4). To get it to work, replace `geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)` with `geom_bar()`